# Unknown column error with has_one association and join in named scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a product and payment_notification model with the following association

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :payment_notification
end

class PaymentNotification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
end
```

I'm setting up a named scope which should fetch all products whose associated payment_notification has the status completed.

I was under the impression that this should work in my Product model:

```
scope :completed, joins(:payment_notification).where(:payment_notification => { :status => 'Completed' })
```

But this results in the following error:

```
Error: Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'payment_notification.status' in 'where clause': SELECT     `products`.* FROM       `items`  INNER JOIN `payment_notifications` ON `payment_notifications`.`product_id` = `productss`.`id` WHERE     (`payment_notification`.`status` = 'Completed')
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Just learned from this how to use the hash and join together, which is not mentioned in the ActiveRelation query guide. Thank you! Very useful for taking in an array in params[] and building a query based on the params.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
scope :completed, joins(:payment_notification).where(:payment_notifications => 
                    { :status => 'Completed' })
```

Notice the plural : `payment_notifications`.